# How to show calltips in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

When writing code in IDLE, sometimes when I insert a function like `re.sub(` in the example, a window pops up explaining the function and the inputs it needs. I find this very helpful and would like to have this window pop up every time. I googled and tried different key combinations but I can't see to find how you do this.

Can somebody help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create my own "hint" when calling a function in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981747/how-can-i-create-my-own-hint-when-calling-a-function-in-python-2-7)

Comment: The questions are different.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, but I think the idea behind both is the same: "What are the calltips and how do they work?"

Comment: I wish to remove all that. sometimes its disturbing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is specific to the python IDLE. In IDLE, you have this functionality enabled by default. For it to work, the function (or method) has to be available in the current namespace.That means it has to either be defined in the running environment, or imported in to the running environment.

For example:

```
>>> def foo(x)
        """the foo function"""
        return x
```

when you type `>>> foo(` in the prompt after the definition, you will see the explanation which really is the documentation contained in the docstring (the stuff between the triple quotes).

If a function or method does not have any documentation, then you will not see any explanation. For example

```
>>> def bar(y):
        return y
```

In this case when you type in `bar(` at the prompt, IDLE will just show `y`, this is because the function does not have any documentation.

Some built in functions (called `builtins`) do not have docstrings, often this is because they are implemented in the C programming language. For example

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(
```

In this case IDLE will not give any hint because the function does not have any docstring for it to display.

A great companion to learning is the [python standard reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). You can lookup built in function definitions there for clear explanations about what they do. On the other hand, when writing your own functions, remember to put docstrings as they will help you as you go on.

Comment: AFAIK, all built-in functions have a docstring, including `reduce`.  Absence would be a bug.  For reduce, the first line is 'reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value',  the reduce signature, and for me, this is what the calltip contains.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple if you want a key combination to show calltip.

Just type "ctrl+\" as shown in the picture here:

[image: Screenshot of menu bar]

One thing to remember it will only work when you have already typed the opening parenthesis and not before.

As shown in the screenshots below:

Parenthesis opened
[image: Parenthesis opened]

Inside the Parenthesis
[image: Inside the Parenthesis]

Without opening parenthesis
[image: Without opening parenthesis]

Answer (score 0):

IDLE's calltips contain the function signature (if directly available) followed by the beginning of the docstring (if there is one).  For builtins that have not gotten the 'Argument Clinic' treatment, the signature is the beginning of the docstring.  This is the case for `reduce`.  In 3.6 and 3.7, when I type `reduce(` after the import and prompt, the calltip contains the signature as given in the docstring.  To see the entire reduce() docstring, use `>>> help(reduce)` or enter `reduce.__doc__`.

To see more calltips when editing in the editor, run your code after entering the import statements.  For instance, if you start IDLE and immediate edit a new file and enter

```
import reduce
reduce(
```

you see no calltip, as you described in your question.  But if you hit F5 after the import and return to the editor, you will.  Similarly, if you want to see calltips for your own functions, run the file occasionally after defining them.